# How to create OR statements for NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

When creating a criteria for NHibernate all criteria are added as `AND`.

For instance:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(someobject))
.Add(critiera)
.Add(other_criteria)
```

then end result will be

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE criteria **AND** other_criteria
```

I would like to tell NHibernate to add the criterias as "OR"

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
 WHERE criteria **OR** other_criteria
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're looking for the `Conjunction` and `Disjunction` classes, these can be used to combine various statements to form OR and AND statements.

**AND**

```
.Add(
  Expression.Conjunction()
    .Add(criteria)
    .Add(other_criteria)
)
```

**OR**

```
.Add(
  Expression.Disjunction()
    .Add(criteria)
    .Add(other_criteria)
)
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `Restrictions.Disjunction()`

```
        var re1 = Restrictions.Eq(prop1, prop_value1);
        var re2 = Restrictions.Eq(prop2, prop_value2);
        var re3 = Restrictions.Eq(prop3, prop_value3);

        var or = Restrictions.Disjunction();
        or.Add(re1).Add(re2).Add(re3);

        criteria.Add(or);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Restrictions.or`, such that:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(someobject))
    .Add(critiera)
    .Add(other_criteria);
```

where:

```
other_criteria = Restrictions.or("property", "value");
```

You can learn more about this following the [Criteria Interface documentation of Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#add(org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion)), which is the same as NHibernate.