# NHIbernate OR Criteria Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

I have the following mapped classes

```
Trade { ID, AccountFrom, AccountTo }
Account {ID, Company}
Company {ID}
```

Now I cannot figure out a way select all trades where

```
AccountFrom.Company.ID = X OR AccountTo.Company.ID = X
```

I can get AND to work using the following:

```
criteria.CreateCriteria("AccountFrom").CreateCriteria("Company").Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID", X);
criteria.CreateCriteria("AccountTo").CreateCriteria("Company").Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID", X);
```

But how can I transform this into an OR rather an an AND. I have used Disjunction previously, but I cannot seem to know how to add separate criteria, just restrictions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
return session.CreateCriteria<Trade>()
    .CreateAlias("AccountFrom", "af")
    .CreateAlias("AccountTo", "at")
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Eq("af.Company.CompanyId", companyId), 
        Restrictions.Eq("at.Company.CompanyId", companyId)))
    .List<Trade>();
```

I don't think you will need to alias Company.

Answer (score 5):

*I think your NHibernate options depend on which version of NHibernate that you are using.*

Disjunction = OR, Conjunction = AND

```
.Add(
  Expression.Disjunction()
    .Add(companyId1)
    .Add(companyId2)
)
```

Same as this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386308)

---

Jamie Ide just answered more thoroughly...the gist of it goes like this:

```
.Add(Restrictions.Or(
    Restrictions.Eq("object1.property1", criteriaValue), 
    Restrictions.Eq("object2.property3", criteriaValue))
```

Comment: But how do I add nested objects? I don't need restrictions on a single property, I need an OR between 2 different properties (on 2 different sub classes)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't give details...'Jamie Ide' just did though.  That should be what you want, and what I should have said.

.Add(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Eq("object1.property1", criteriaValue), 
        Restrictions.Eq("object2.property3", criteriaValue))

Answer (score 3):

Using Linq to NHibernate:

```
var X = 0; // or whatever the identifier type.
var result = Session.Linq<Trade>()
                 .Where(trade => trade.AccountFrom.Company.ID == X ||
                                 trade.AccountTo.Company.ID == X)
                 .ToList();
```

Using HQL:

```
var X = 0; // or whatever the identifier type.
var hql = "from Trade trade where trade.AccountFrom.Company.ID = :companyId or trade.AccountTo.Company.ID = :companyID";
var result = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
                 .SetParameter("companyId", X)
                 .List<Trade>();
```