# nhibernate c# criteria to retrieve null values

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to retrieve files with a status file = 10 and null values form a nullable VARCHAR2 column from an oracle db.

After some searching I found the following:

```
ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType);  
criteria.Add(Expression.In("StatusFile", 10));
criteria.Add(Restrictions.IsEmpty("StatusFile"));
```

In sql would be something like:

```
select attstatus from table where file_tmode = 'P'and  (status is null or status = 10);
```

If I remove the last line, it works, but I have not been able to find a way to add the criteria for the null values.

How could I do this?

Comment: Could you explain what you want a bit more clearly? Do you want `StatusFile = 10 OR StatusFile IS NULL`?

Comment: Hi. I need to retrieve both, StatusFile = 10 and StatusFile is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `IsNull`?

```
NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType)
  .Add(Expression.In("StatusFile", 10))
  .Add(Expression.IsNull("StatusFile"));
```

using `or`

```
NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType)
  .Add(Expression.In("StatusFile", 10)
    || Expression.IsNull("StatusFile"));
```

Note that nulls are not indexed in oracle (at least a few years ago when I used it) and it may be very slow to find null values in a large table.

Comment: This way does not throws an exception the way the one I had does, but nhibertate interprets it "StatusFile in (10) and StatusFile is null", and it does not retrieve any values.

Comment: here is an explenation for an or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299022/nhibernate-or-criteria-query

Answer (score 2):

```
ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType);  
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Or (
    Restrictions.Eq ("StatusFile", 10), 
    Restrictions.IsNull ("StatusFile)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

.List()
Since Stefan Steinegger's answer is 'and'ing your critieria, why don't you try disjunction ('or'ing)?
Something like this,  -

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<PersistentType>();
var disjunction = new Disjunction();   
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<PersistentType>(obj => obj.statusFile == 10));
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<PersistentType>(obj => obj.statusFile == null));
var queryResult = query.Where(disjunction).List<PersistentType>();
```

Or simply,

```
var queryResult = Session.QueryOver<PersistentType>()
    .Where(obj => obj.statusFile == 10 || obj.statusFile == null).List<PersistentType>();
```