# NHibernate Filter based on a List<T>

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernet 3.1 for .Net and I have this scenario.

**ClassA.cs**

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual string ID_1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string ID_2 { get; set; }

    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**ClassA.hbm.xml**

```
  <class name="ClassA" table="TableA" lazy="false">
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="ID_1" column="ID_1" />
      <key-property name="ID_2" column="ID_2" />
    </composite-id>

    <property name="Nome">
      <column name="Nome" sql-type="varchar" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
```

I have a list `List<ClassA>` and I need to filter `TableA` based on this List, how could I do that ?

```
List ClassA
| 1 | 1 | Teste1 |
| 2 | 3 | Teste3 |

TableA
| 1 | 1 | Teste1 |
| 2 | 2 | Teste2 |
| 2 | 3 | Teste3 |
| 2 | 4 | Teste4 |

Result must be
| 1 | 1 | Teste1 |
| 2 | 3 | Teste3 |
```

Comment: Why can't you use a linq Contains query?

Comment: I could do, any suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I got another code with Criteria,

```
Disjunction ConjuntoOr = Restrictions.Disjunction();

foreach (ClassA item in itens)
{ 
   ConjuntoOr.Add
   (
      Expression.Conjunction()
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID_1", item.ID_1))
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID_2", item.ID_2))
   );
}

ICriteria criteria =
   mySession
      .CreateCriteria<ClassA>()
      .Add(ConjuntoOr)
      .List<ClassA>();
```

Query genereted by NHibernate

```
NHibernate: 
SELECT 
    this_.ID_1 as COD1_6_0_, 
    this_.ID_2 as COD2_6_0_,
    this_.Nome as NOME3_6_0_
FROM 
    dbo.TableA this_ 
WHERE 
    (
        (this_.ID_1 = @p0 and this_.ID_2 = @p1) or 
        (this_.ID_1 = @p2 and this_.ID_2 = @p3)
    );

@p0 = '1' [Type: String (4000)], @p1 = '1' [Type: String (4000)], 
@p2 = '2' [Type: String (4000)], @p3 = '3' [Type: String (4000)]
```

This was pretty much what I was looking for.
Thx for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386308/how-to-create-or-statements-for-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0):

so

```
var classAList = List<ClassA> { new ClassA { ... }, ....};

var containsClassAList = mySession.Query<ClassA>().Where(c => classAList.Contains(c));
```

something like that.  the above is pseudo code.  I don't have an nhibernate project in front of me right now.  But I've used contains before. You could also try All();

Comment: I got an error on this query, I couldn't fit two columns on it. I will keep looking for another solution

Comment: you wouldn't fit 2 columns into it, you'd send the entire class.

Comment: I am sry but I think I could apply the code like you said. I got errors and I wasnt able to set which columns I want to filter, which in this case are only two from three columns.